# How to disable stack with flycheck for Haskell?

Tags: flycheck, haskell-mode

I'm on nixos and due to stack's integration with Nix/Nixos the following command is very slow:

```
time stack ghc
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
stack ghc  1.14s user 0.13s system 95% cpu 1.324 total
```

This means after a few keystrokes the emacs editor hangs... So I usually uninstall stack to remove it from the `$PATH`.

How can I disable this, to avoid this really frustrating delay?

In the messages:

```
haskell-stack-ghc: Flycheck checker haskell-stack-ghc returned non-zero exit code 1,
```

I have tried adding:

```
(add-to-list '(flycheck-disabled-checkers '(haskell-stack-ghc)))
```

to my init file, but there was no change in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
(add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'haskell-stack-ghc)
```

The first argument to `add-to-list` is the name (more precisely the symbol) of the variable to modify. The second argument is the element (here again a symbol) to add. Both symbols need to be quoted since you need to pass the symbol itself to the function and not the value that the variable is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

```
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(haskell-stack-ghc))
```

I had to set the above...